# Building a variable's template type from a different variables template type

Tags: c++, templates, design-patterns

If I have a variable whose type was a templated class, and I want to build another variable of a different templated class, but use the same template parameter, how could I?

While the example below does not work, it hopefully gives the idea of what I am looking to accomplish. If there is no very specific way to do this, is there a way to have some sort of a lookup table design pattern to do this? There is only six or so different templated types I will probably end up using.

```
template<typename T>
class A{
public:
    typedef T Type;
};

template<typename T>
class B{};

int main(void){
    A<int> var1;

    B<var1::Type> var2;
}
```

My apologies if this is a duplicate question, but I did not see anything like this asked before.

**EDIT**

I would like a way for this to work with Visual Studio 2010 AND gcc, without using a third party library. So not all C++ 11 features may be supported.

Also, without using a `typedef A<int>` or knowing `A<int>` as this code is simply a test case scenario to show basic functionality of what I want. I want a way to get the template type from the variable whose type was a template.

Comment: FWIW, to get your example to compile, change `A<int> var1;` to `typedef A<int> var1;`

Comment: @Jesse the point is that `var1` is a variable, not a type.

Comment: OK, I added another variant that should work in VS2010, although I cannot test that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even with VC++ 2010's pre-standardized decltype, I think you might be able to do something like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct A {
    typedef T Type;
    Type foo();
};

template<typename T>
struct B {};

int main() {
    A<int> var1;
    B<decltype(var1.foo())> var2;
}
```

This depends on being able to form some expression that uses the type you want.

Answer (score 2):

In C++11 you can use `decltype`:

```
B<decltype(var1)::Type> var2;
```

and it should work. See decltype [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decltype).

If you want to do something similar in C++03, you could try applying your functionality inside a templated function:

```
template <typename T>
void doSomething(const T& var1) {

  B<typename T::Type> var2;
  // do whatever you wanted to do with var2 here.
  // problem is, you cannot return it.
  std::cout << "Doing something!\n";

}

int main(void){
    A<int> var1;
    doSomething(var1);
}
```

**Edit:** Thanks to @MSalters for pointing out that you have the `auto` keyword in VS2010, so one can define this function:

```
template <typename T>
B<typename T::Type> makeB(const T&) {
  return B<typename T::Type>();
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
int main(void){
    A<int> var1;
    auto var2 = makeB(var1);
}
```

Comment: @mmurphy OK, fixed for C++11. I will see if I can come up with the equivalent C++03 template magic.

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately that does not seem to compile for my current compiler (Visual Studio 2010).

Comment: @mmurphy accodring to [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee336130.aspx) decltype is supported in VS 2010. But maybe you need a `typename` in there: B<typename decltype(..... )>?

Comment: I just read the documentation you provided and it seems as if decltype is supported in VS2010, I just suppose the way it is being used here is incorrect. Even with typename it will provide nearly the same errors.

Comment: The rules for using `decltype` before `::` was changed after the release of VS2010. It is allowed in C++11 but wasn't in the draft standard a year earlier.

Comment: @BoPersson: Well that is unfortunate. Do you know of a way to do this with VS2010?

Comment: No, there is no easy way of doing this. That's one reason for adding the new rules to C++11. :-)

Comment: @Bo Persson: Whats the hard way of doing this then? ;)

Comment: @mmurphy I added an example of a template function that makes a `B<A<T>::Type>` given an instance of `A<int>`. The problem is that it is not easy to define a function that returns the `B<>` since one has to determine the return type, and there lies the crux of the matter.

Comment: Seems easy actually: `template<typename T> B<typename T::Type> doSomething(const T& var1);`. Doesn't even need the C++11 alternative `auto` syntax.

Comment: @MSalters I-m not sure that works, but in any case, what would the caller do without `auto`?

Comment: Well, pass it to another templated function ;) But indeed, the real problem is storing the return value. I do think @mmurphy can use `auto` in VS2010 for that, but in C++03 you're out of options.

Comment: Thank you for the help, those are some very excellent examples.